# How do I create a table based on another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, create-table

I want to create a table based on the definition of another table.

I'm coming from oracle and I'd normally do this:

```
 CREATE TABLE schema.newtable AS SELECT * FROM schema.oldtable;
```

I can't seem to be able to do this in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There is no such syntax in SQL Server, though `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT` does exist in data warehouse technologies (like APS / [dedicated pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas)). In SQL Server you can use this query to create an empty table:

```
SELECT * INTO {schema_name}.newtable 
  FROM {schema_name}.oldtable 
  WHERE 1 = 0;
```

(If you want to make a copy of the table *including* all of the data, then leave out the `WHERE` clause.)

Note that this creates the same column structure (including an `IDENTITY` column if one exists) but it does not copy any indexes, constraints, triggers, etc.

If you don't want to keep the `IDENTITY` property, you can just convert it first to its original data type:

```
SELECT IdentityColumn = CONVERT(int/bigint, IdentityColumn),
  ...other columns...
```

Comment: works for me...dont know what PDW is though :)

Comment: PDW stands for Paralel Data Warehouse, is now part as [Microsoft Analytics Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/analytics-platform-system/).

Comment: What does 'WHERE 1 = 0' mean?

Comment: It means create the table with 0 rows (since no row can be returned where `1 = 0` is true).

Comment: How would you use this query but also keep the IDENTITY Columns (including any Keys and Indexes)? Is that even possible or would I have to create the table first then use INSERT INTO?

Comment: @Daisy `SELECT INTO` will keep IDENTITY columns by default, but other constraints and indexes, you're going to have to create yourself.

Comment: In my case, with SQL SERVER, schema isn't recognized. But this works :

SELECT * INTO newtable 
  FROM oldtable 
  WHERE 1 = 0;

Comment: @nhey4Aterno That is meant as a placeholder for your actual schema name, usually just `dbo`.

Answer (score 22):

```
select * into newtable from oldtable
```

Comment: this is a ms sql server question

Comment: @Jonathan And what is the problem?

Comment: Does this preserve the types of the columns precisely or does it "compact" the data? For example, choosing `varchar(5)` instead of `varchar(20)` because none of the values were longer than 5 characters?

Comment: @Leonid I haven't found any written source, but it looks like it preserves the structure exactly:
`CREATE TABLE #origin (how_long varchar(50))

SELECT * INTO #new FROM #origin WHERE 1 = 0

EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#new'`

Comment: This is not a corrrect answer, since CREATE...LIKE only copies schema,  and no data is copied, but this query copies data as well

Comment: ```SELECT TOP 0 *``` could just copy the table schema without the data