# SQL: Create new table from old

Tags: sql

I am trying to create one new table with the selective columns from the existing table. I used the following query,

```
create table New 
AS (select UnitID,Institution,State,MSA from Old);
```

But I am getting the error as,

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

If I remove those ()-brackets it is saying ()-brackets are expected near AS.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a table based on another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254104/how-do-i-create-a-table-based-on-another-table)

Comment: Both `New` and `Old` are reserved words, need to be delimited as `"Old"` and `"New"`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, both old and new have been reserved words since ISO/ANSI SQL-1999.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Just for your information: the way you try to this SQL expects the definitions for the columns of table to create between the brackets, not a SQL statement reading data from another table. So this is just a syntax error. The answer bellow (with SELECT...INTO) will do the trick. This works, but the preferred way would be to create a new table and copy the data into it. This will give you much more control over what happens.

Comment: @Tom: that depends on the DBMS. That syntax **is** valid (and standard SQL). It the DBMS is Oracle this will probably fail because `old` and `new` are reserved keywords in Oracle (as jarlh mentioned) and can't be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **basic syntax** for creating a new table from old table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS
SELECT [ column1, column2...columnN ]
FROM OLD_TABLE_NAME
[ WHERE ]
```

Consider EMPLOYEE_DETAILS as new table name and EMPLOYEE as old table name

**example code:**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS AS
 SELECT ID, SALARY
   FROM EMPLOYEE;
```