# Create tables using SELECT INTO

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

How to execute the following raw query using SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT *
INTO <table-1>
FROM <table-2>
WHERE condition=<1>
```

I am working with Microsoft SQL server. And when I run this

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla

engine_string = "mssql://%s/%s?driver=%s" % (server_name, database_name, driver)
con = sqla.create_engine(engine_string)
query_str = <above-query>
con.execute(query)
```

It executes without any errors, but there is no table created. What's happening here?

Comment: You want to create a table? That SQL is a selection query. You might want to look into the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Have you tried designating the schema as shown in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254104/how-do-i-create-a-table-based-on-another-table

Comment: @Isma The query I have written works on the MS SQL Server. It pushes the results of select query into the table mentioned.

Comment: @brddawg The query runs and creates a table when I run it directly in MS SQL server management studio. What I want is to create it using sqlalchemy.

Comment: You are right, that should create the table automatically. Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575111/how-to-create-a-new-table-from-select-statement-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: I came across this answer in my search. It seemed too complex to do such a simple thing. Normal select queries work properly through the way I am executing so I was hoping that this would work too. It shouldn't matter if no rows are being returned.

Comment: Does `table-1` name start with # sign (for a temporary table)?

Comment: @wdosanjos no. That is an issue for another question I think. I was not even able to run a select query from a temp table through sqlalchemy. That's why I started making a permanent table.

Comment: The reason your original textual SQL seems to fail is that it never commits. Read [understanding autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit). Tl;dr: SQLAlchemy inspects the textual SQL statement, sees that it starts with SELECT and deems it non data modifying. And please rename `con` to `engine`, which it is.

Comment: @IljaEverilä that seems to be in the right direction. I'll try it with ```autocommit=False``` and report back. And yeah didn't even notice the ```con``` part. Will change it in my code. :)

Comment: If you use `Engine.execute()`, then try wrapping your SQL text with `text(query).execution_options(autocommit=True)`, which informs the autocommit machinery that this statement should be committed.

Comment: @IljaEverilä the above method works. Should I delete this question?

Comment: The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209793/2445273).